# Running CameraBridgeViewBase as a service to do movement detection in background using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, service, camera

So I'm trying to write part of some code for a robot that eventually will be driving around our office.

We are using a tablet that will do some face recognition and will also, at the same time function as a projection for an animated face to greet customers.

At this point I have a simple app that can do some basic movement detection while it is running on the foreground.

I'm starting to encounter problems now that I have to change the app to a service so it can continuously run in the background while the "animated face app" can run in the foreground.

The biggest, and final hurdle that is still in my way is the following:

Because the activity is a service I can't seem to find a way to instantiate the CameraBridgeViewBase in the service part:

```
mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.show_camera_activity_java_surface_view);
```

This will throw an error because findViewById is not a callable function in a Service.

I have tried many things, making the CameraBridgeViewBase serializable, parceable and passing it as an object attached to an Intent to the service but to no succes.

This is from the Main_activity_show_camera_service.java:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags,int startId) {
    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.show_camera_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(400,300);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Which will crash on the findViewById command.

And this is just the function on the button to start the service:

```
    public void startService(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity_show_camera_service.class);
    startService(i);
}
```

I know there are a lot of other libraries and ways to get the same result and I will most certainly be looking into these but I'd just like to be able to use OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help possible people in the future:
This is the Service code I eventually ended up with that works for me. It makes use of the new camera2 API.

```
package com.example.stemmeriky.testapplication;
//imports 

public class MainActivity_show_camera_service extends Service  {
private List<MatOfPoint> contours;
private int mWidth = 480;
private int mHeight = 320;
private Mat mFGMask;
private BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 fgbg;
private Handler mCameraHandler;
private static int counter = 0;
private ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
public int threshold = 650;
private Surface mCameraRecieverSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();


private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                fgbg = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
                contours = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void convertImageToMat(Mat inputFrame) throws FileNotFoundException {
    contours.clear();
    fgbg.apply(inputFrame, mFGMask, 0.1);
    Imgproc.findContours(mFGMask, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    if (contours.size() > threshold) {
        System.out.println("movement detected");//           
savePicture(inputFrame);
    }
}


public static Mat imageToMat(Image image) {
    ByteBuffer buffer;
    int rowStride;
    int pixelStride;
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int offset = 0;

    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    byte[] data = new byte[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8];
    byte[] rowData = new byte[planes[0].getRowStride()];

    for (int i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
        buffer = planes[i].getBuffer();
        rowStride = planes[i].getRowStride();
        pixelStride = planes[i].getPixelStride();
        int w = (i == 0) ? width : width / 2;
        int h = (i == 0) ? height : height / 2;
        for (int row = 0; row < h; row++) {
            int bytesPerPixel = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8;
            if (pixelStride == bytesPerPixel) {
                int length = w * bytesPerPixel;
                buffer.get(data, offset, length);

                // Advance buffer the remainder of the row stride, unless on the last row.
                // Otherwise, this will throw an IllegalArgumentException because the buffer
                // doesn't include the last padding.
                if (h - row != 1) {
                    buffer.position(buffer.position() + rowStride - length);
                }
                offset += length;
            } else {

                // On the last row only read the width of the image minus the pixel stride
                // plus one. Otherwise, this will throw a BufferUnderflowException because the
                // buffer doesn't include the last padding.
                if (h - row == 1) {
                    buffer.get(rowData, 0, width - pixelStride + 1);
                } else {
                    buffer.get(rowData, 0, rowStride);
                }

                for (int col = 0; col < w; col++) {
                    data[offset++] = rowData[col * pixelStride];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Finally, create the Mat.
    Mat mat = new Mat(height + height / 2, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mat.put(0, 0, data);

    return mat;
}

public void savePicture(Mat image) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File RobotPhotoDirectory = new File(storage + "/Pictures/RobotPhotoDirectory/");
    if (!RobotPhotoDirectory.exists()) {
        RobotPhotoDirectory.mkdir();
    }
    String dir_path = RobotPhotoDirectory + "/";
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(dir_path + File.separator + "testfile" + counter + ".jpg", image);
    counter++;
}

ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mImageAvailListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        try {
            convertImageToMat(imageToMat(image));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        image.close();
    }
};

{
    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mImageAvailListener, mCameraHandler);
}

MainActivity_show_camera_service() {
    HandlerThread mCameraHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("mCameraHandlerThread");
    mCameraHandlerThread.start();
    mCameraHandler = new Handler(mCameraHandlerThread.getLooper());
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void startProducing() {
    CameraManager cm = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String[] cameraList = cm.getCameraIdList();
        for (String cd : cameraList) {
            CameraCharacteristics mCameraCharacteristics = cm.getCameraCharacteristics(cd);
            if (mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) != CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            cm.openCamera(cd, mDeviceStateCallback, mCameraHandler);
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        List<Surface> surfaceList = new ArrayList<>();
        surfaceList.add(mCameraRecieverSurface);

        try {
            camera.createCaptureSession(surfaceList, mCaptureSessionStateCallback, mCameraHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException ignored) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {

    }
};


public void onCreate() {
    System.out.println("onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
    mFGMask = new Mat();
    startProducing();
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private final CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback mCaptureSessionStateCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = session.getDevice().createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            requestBuilder.addTarget(mCameraRecieverSurface);
            //set to null - image data will be produced but will not receive metadata
            session.setRepeatingRequest(requestBuilder.build(), null, mCameraHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
    }
};
```

}